# What is the Taylor Series for $\frac{1}{x-1}$ at $x=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

In taylor series we know that,
$f(a) + f'(a)\frac{(x-a)}{1!} + f''(a)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}+...$

Here if we put $a=0$,
we found $f(0)= undefined$

So how can I find out the whole series?

Comment: $1/(x-1)$ is well defined at $0$.

Comment: $f(0)=-1 $ etc.

Comment: If you meant about $a=1$ instead then this function doesn't have a Taylor series representation because no matter how you define $f(1)$ the function won't be continuous/differentiable there. We would need to consider a Laurent series expansion instead.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I want to see the process

Comment: You may want to see the process. However, I’d like to see why you say it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You have two methods to find
,if you know geometrics$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...,|x|<1 \to \\
\frac 1{x-1}=-\frac 1{1-x}=\\-(1+x+x^2+...)=-1-x-x^2-x^3-x^4-x^5-...$$
whenever you insist to find with $f(a) + f'(a)\frac{(x-a)}{1!} + f''(a)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}+...$
yo may rewrite $\frac{1}{x-1}=(x-1)^{-1}$so
$$f(0)=-1\\f'(x)=-1(x-1)^{-2}\to f'(0)=-1\\
f''(x)=+1.2(x-1)^{-3}\to f''(0)=-1.2\\
f'''(x)=-1.2.3(x-1)^{-4}\to f'''(0)=-1.2.3\\$$and  so on , the result is the same.
$$f(0) + f'(0)\frac{(x-0)}{1!} + f''(0)\frac{(x-0)^2}{2!}+...\\=-1+(-1)x-\frac{1.2}{2!}x^2-\frac{1.2.3}{3!}x^3-...$$